# iOS - Inapp Purchases - setting in server

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am creating iOS app with in-app purchase feature in it.
I created the app id, profile etc successfully.
I also added the in-app purchase ID, etc in apple's itunes connect.
But on the top I'm seeing the following message:

**Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.**

I didn't understand what does it mean?
When I'm testing, i'm not getting response from server. 
how to identify and correct the issue.

this is my first app that will be pushed to app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the bundle id for the app is created, app store app is created, in-app purchase id's are created, we need to push dummy app and immediately reject it.
Then only in-app purchases work. else it wont